# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Boolean

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn how to develop an Android App. I'm going over the standard exercise 'Notepadv3' [LINK](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad) and adapting it for my purposes.

It is a database orientated class that previously (in the exercise) had two string fields.  I want to add a boolean field to allow for a value that says if the record is completed.

It starts with this, I added a 'CheckBox' variable, is this right?:

```
public class TaskEdit extends Activity {

private EditText mTitleText;
private EditText mBodyText;
private CheckBox mCompleteBoolean; /* <<< - I added this, is this right */
private Long mRowId;
private TasksDbAdapter mDbHelper;
```

Then I'm having trouble with the following method:

```
private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String body = mBodyText.getText().toString(); /* Copied this line to the one below, but need a boolean field */
    Boolean complete = mCompleteBoolean.getText().toString(); /* << Not working as Boolean - getting 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Boolean' << */

    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.createTask(title, body, complete); 
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateTask(mRowId, title, body, complete); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the error means? What could `getText` and `toString` mean or do? (Assuming you hadn't read the documentation.)

Comment: [`Boolean.valueOf(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html - use the `isChecked()` method to get a boolean from a checkbox.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis, you may not have meant it as such, but your comment appears highly non-constructive and patronising.  I'm not familiar with java and it is extremely confusing.

Comment: Whymarrh Sorry, really don't understand your comment, but don't worry my problem has been resolved. Thank you for trying to assist.

Comment: DNA, thanks for attempting to put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to do this:

```
 Boolean complete = mCompleteBoolean.isChecked();
```

there is a self-explaining [isChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29) method available that will return a boolean value.

Comment: donfuxx, thanks for the clear, straight to the point response.  I did read the documentation, but a lot of it does not make sense (to me at the moment), hence why I'm slowly adapting existing code to help me understand along the way. Again, thanks.